# SQL statistics query

Tags: sql, database, statistics

I want to gather some statistics and I wonder if can take some min, max and average values directly by DB queries.

In an oversimplification I have something like this:

```
Person  | Account
__________________
Person1 | Account1
Person1 | Account2
Person1 | Account3
Person2 | Account4
Person2 | Account5
..................
```

I want to find the maximum, minimum and average number of accounts a person has. Is this possible with a SQL query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select
    min(accountcount),
    avg(accountcount),
    max(accountcount)
from
(
    select 
        person, count(*) as accountcount
    from 
        yourtable
    group by person
) v
```

`AVG` will return the mean, as opposed to any other kind of average.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could use [aggregate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) functions to perform this type of operation:

`MAX()`
  `MIN()`
  `AVG()`

```
select max(cnt), min(cnt), avg(cnt)
from
(
    select person, count(*) cnt
    from yourtable
    group by person
) x
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to group by person and then subquery that, something like this:

```
SELECT MIN(PersonCount), MAX(PersonCount), AVG(PersonCount) FROM 
(SELECT Person, COUNT(*) AS PersonCount FROM PersonAccounts GROUP BY Person)
```

Comment: You'll need an alias for that subquery :)